# Agregar elemento a lista en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Quiero hacer un programa en Python en el que pulsando 1, me imprima una lista de colores y pulsando 2, me dé la opción de añadir un nuevo color y al pulsar nuevamente 1, me aparezca la lista de colores con el nuevo añadido, ¿Qué debo hacer? Esto es lo que tengo:

```
while True:
  print("""¡Bienvenido!
  1-Lista de colores
  2-Añadir color""")
  opcion = int(input("Opción: "))
  if opcion ==1:
    colores={"amarillo","azul","rojo"}
    print("Los colores son: ")
    print(colores)
  elif opcion ==2:
    nuevoColor = input("Introduce color: ")
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Juan. Dos cosas:  no queda muy claro en que contenedor quieres almacenar los datos, en el título y etiqueta mencionas "diccionario", en el cuerpo de la pregunta mencionas "lista" y en tu código no usas ni un diccionario ni una lista, sino que estás usando un conjunto (`set`). Por otro lado, debes formatear tu código correctamente, para ello solo tienes que seleccionarlo y pulsar `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

las listas en python se especifican usando **[ ]** (corchetes), veo quee en tu código usas **{ }** (llaves) lo cual python entiende como diccionarios.

Parar lograr lo que quieres

> Quiero hacer un programa en Python en el que pulsando 1, me imprima una lista de colores y pulsando 2, me dé la opción de añadir un nuevo color y al pulsar nuevamente 1, me aparezca la lista de colores con el nuevo añadido

Debes crear la lista antes del **while** para que no sea nuevamente creado por cada iteración. Por lo que el código debería empezar así:

```
colores=["amarillo","azul","rojo"]  # Las listas en python se indican con [ ]
while True:
```

Fíjate que ahora usa [ ] en vez de {}

Ahora solo queda agregar el color cuando el usuario ingrese "2", en esa condición quedaría así:

```
elif opcion ==2:
    nuevoColor = input("Introduce color: ")
    colores.append(nuevoColor)
```

Te recomiendo leer más acerca de las **listas en python**
Aquí te dejo el código completo:

```
colores=["amarillo","azul","rojo"]
while True:
print("""¡Bienvenido!
    1-Lista de colores
    2-Añadir color""")
opcion = int(input("Opción: "))
if opcion ==1:
    print("Los colores son: ")
    print(colores)
elif opcion ==2:
    nuevoColor = input("Introduce color: ")
    colores.append(nuevoColor)
```

Comment: Como aclaración, python no entiende los corchetes necesariamente como diccionarios, pueden ser conjuntos.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set